# C# control array as a method overload

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, controls, overloading

In my program there are multiple players who's stats can all be increased at the same time.

> Player 1 is represented by staminaTextBox[0] skillTextBox[0] LuckTexBox[0]
>
> Player 2 is represented by staminaTextBox[1] skillTextBox[1] LuckTexBox[1]
>
> etc.

I need my `IncreaseStat` method to deal with 3 different type of Textbox Overload e.g. Stamina, Skill, Luck

```
private void StaminaIncBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncreaseStat(staminaText[0]);
}

private void LuckIncBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncreaseStat(luckText[0]);
}

private void IncreaseStat(TextBox statText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        statText[i].Text = "Altered";
    }
}
```

This method is used to increase all 5 players stats at the same time.

It works fine if they are not control arrays, however I need them to be. I get the error
`"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"`. It applies to that fact that inside the method I am saying `statText[i]`.

I do not understand how to get around this problem. Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: .NET doesn't have control arrays as such (not like VB6 has) - how have you created these?

Comment: Your game logic is tied too tightly to the UI.

Comment: statText is a single Textbox not an array of Textboxes.

Comment: You can create control arrays if you just dynmaicaly create them e.g.

TextBox[] SkillTextbox = new TextBox[5]

Comment: The game is just for recording tabletop roleplaying. E.g. me nad my 3 friends get hit 5 damage. So i use the form to keep track of our health instead of pen and paper

Comment: As a rule it's a bad idea to use UI controls to store your data.  You should have a `Player` object which stores the information, and then have functions to either display the information from a `Player` into the UI, or get a `Player` object representing what's in the UI (after a user changes something).  To update a value from code you should just update the underlying collection of Players.  You can use techniques such as Data Binding to help with the transition between objects and UI controls.

Comment: If i say statText[5] it gives the same error. The logic work if i'm just doing it for 1 type of textbox. Just not if a textbox parameter is given.

Comment: @Ralt: Because control arrays don't exist unless you dynamically build your form. My answer may give you some insight into what you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be sufficient (with possible changes by yourself for your need)?

```
private void IncreaseStat() {
    foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("stamina") || 
            x.Name.Contains("skill") || 
            x.Name.Contains("Luck"))) {
        textBox.Text = "Altered";
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic worked thank you. Needed to alter it a bit like you said. Thanks for your time!